# Call Symfony Service on demand from twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I've created a twig template that will create a table of items with checkboxes and a js function that can be triggered using a button that will return the IDs of all items where the checkboxes are checked. This works fine so far. Now I need to call a service and pass an array of all selected IDs.

Is there a good way to call the service from within the js part in the twig template? I don't want to create a controller for the service and use curl to call it.

Best regards Christian

Comment: From js you can't do only ajax, so controller

Answer (score 12):

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        myService: "@my.service"
```

And in twig you can use now:

```
{{ myService.anyMethod() }}
```

You can also make Twig extension:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Yes I've read about these extensions and services, but I guess they will be called when the page loads. I want to trigger it later when the user clicks the button

Comment: O, sorr I didn't understood this at first. There is no way on calling service methods from client side (ex. js) this is how HTTP protocol works, Client sends request, server processes it and than return response. There is no keeping connection for browser and server. You can do it by ajax calls to some controller actions - no need to make curls.

Comment: In my case, in Symfony 3.4 I had to declare my service this way: ```my_service: '@AppBundle\Service\MyService'```. Otherwise, I was getting a ```ServiceNotFoundException``` exception.